# Target type std.standard.bit in variable assignment is different from std_logic_1164.std_ulogic?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, hardware

Sorry if the format is not good but I'm new with that..
I'm trying to select a bit from an unsigned signal to be assigned to a bit variable but it doesn't work!! 
I've tried to assign it in a process but it doesn't work too 
The following errors appear

```
** Error: D:/Electronic Engineering Faculty/FeeSparc/The_very_last source_code/cache_mem/cache_mem.vhd(70): Target type std.standard.bit in variable assignment is different from expression type ieee.std_logic_1164.std_ulogic.
** Error: D:/Electronic Engineering Faculty/FeeSparc/The_very_last source_code/cache_mem/cache_mem.vhd(71): Target type std.standard.bit in variable assignment is different from expression type ieee.std_logic_1164.std_ulogic.
** Error: D:/Electronic Engineering Faculty/FeeSparc/The_very_last source_code/cache_mem/cache_mem.vhd(114): VHDL Compiler exiting
```

Any help with that please?

```
--Cache design
--2 sets, 2 ways, block size=4 words
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity cache_mem is port (
c_add : in unsigned(31 downto 0);
c_d_in : in unsigned(31 downto 0);
c_clk : in bit;
c_wen : in bit; 
c_d_out : out unsigned(31 downto 0);
c_hit : out bit;
c_dirty : out bit;
finish : out bit);
end cache_mem;

architecture arc_cache_mem of cache_mem is
type cache_type is array(79 downto 0) of unsigned(31 downto 0);
signal cache : cache_type;
signal set,sel : integer range 0 to 1000;
signal hit_0,hit_1:bit; 

begin 
--set 0 
  --block 0
cache(0)<=x"00000000";
cache(1)<=x"00000001";
cache(2)<=x"00000002";
cache(3)<=x"00000003";
cache(4)<=x"01000000";
  --block 1
cache(5)<=x"00000005";
cache(6)<=x"00000006";
cache(7)<=x"00000007";
cache(8)<=x"00000008";
cache(9)<=x"01000001";

  --set 1
    --block 0
cache(10)<=x"00000010";
cache(11)<=x"00000011";
cache(12)<=x"00000012";
cache(13)<=x"00000013";
cache(14)<=x"01000002";
  --block 1
cache(15)<=x"00000015";
cache(16)<=x"00000016";
cache(17)<=x"00000017";
cache(18)<=x"00000018";
cache(19)<=x"01000003";




set<=conv_integer(c_add(7 downto 4))*10;
sel<=conv_integer(c_add(3 downto 2));



process(c_clk)
variable dirty_0,dirty_1:bit;  
variable temp_0,temp_1: unsigned (31 downto 0);  
--variable out_0,out_1:unsigned (31 downto 0);
begin
temp_0:=cache(set+4);
temp_1:=cache(set+9);

----HERE IS THE ERROR----

dirty_0:=temp_0(25);
dirty_1:=temp_1(25);


 if(c_add(31 downto 8)=temp_0(23 downto 0) and temp_0(24)='1') then 
   hit_0<='1';
--   case sel is 
--    when 0 => out_0<=cache(set);
--    when 1 => out_0<=cache(set+1);
--    when 2 => out_0<=cache(set+2);
--    when others => out_0<=cache(set+3); 
--  end case;

elsif(c_add(31 downto 8)/=temp_0(23 downto 0) or temp_0(24)='0') then 
  hit_0<='0';
end if;  

if(c_add(31 downto 8)=temp_1(23 downto 0) and temp_1(24)='1') then 
  hit_1<='1';
--    case sel is 
--    when 0 => out_1<=cache(set+5);
--    when 1 => out_1<=cache(set+6);
--    when 2 => out_1<=cache(set+7);
--    when others => out_1<=cache(set+8); 
--    end case;

elsif(c_add(31 downto 8)/=temp_1(23 downto 0) or temp_1(24)='0') then 
  hit_1<='0';
end if; 

if(hit_0='1') then 
--  cache_out<=out_0;
  c_hit<='1';
  c_dirty<=dirty_0;
elsif(hit_1='1') then 
--  cache_out<=out_1;
  c_hit<='1';
  c_dirty<=dirty_1;
else
  c_hit<='0';
  c_dirty<=dirty_0 or dirty_1;
end if;

end process;
end arc_cache_mem;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type 'bit' is rarely used.  Let's call this academic code :-) Change your 'bit' signals and variables to the type 'std_logic' should/could fix your problem. (I did not test it with your code)

BTW: try to avoid using the library 'std_logic_arith'.  Try to use the more modern library 'numeric_std'.  You will find more information about this on this website.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is quite correct - "`bit`" and "`std_logic`" are different types. Bit has two possible values (0 and 1) while std_logic has many more. Both have legitimate uses; depending on the level of detail at which you need to model digital hardware (and the resulting speed or lack of it in simulation)

Converting from one to the other is simple : use the "`to_bit`" and "`to_std_logic`" functions provided by the `ieee.std_logic_1164` library.